# Tailwind :before to all child except first child

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a breadcrumb. I'm trying to separate each item with a content "/" using Tailwind CSS. I have tried this: last:before:content-['/'] but its not working.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="flex" aria-label="Breadcrumb">
  <ul class="flex items-center">
    <li class="flex items-center before:content-['/']">
      <a href="#"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex items-center before:content-['/']">
      <a href="#"> Products </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Right now, it look like this:

```
/Home  /Products
```

I want to look like this:

```
Home / Products
```

Is there any chance to convert this code to Tailwind CSS?

```
li:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "/";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is by creating your own modifiers using addVariant API, read tailwind CSS docs [Creating custom modifiers](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#creating-custom-modifiers)

The addVariant function allows you to register your own custom modifiers that can be used just like the built-in hover, focus, active, etc. variants.

1- Go to `tailwind.config.js` and add this line at the top

```
let plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
```

2- Then define the modifier inside `plugin` like this:

```
plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('slash', 'li:not(:first-child):before')
    }),
  ],
```

3- Use it like this:

```
<ul class="flex items-center space-x-4 slash:content-['/\00a0']">
    <li class="flex items-center">
      <a href="#"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex items-center">
      <a href="#"> Products </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> NOTE: the `\00a0` is just a Unicode for no-break space, you can delete it.

See it [LIVE](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Xho9YF0t3L)